# How to commit a change to a homebrew formula?

Tags: git, homebrew, push

I made a change to some homebrew formula which fixes an issue I had. I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/4517) to get that fix into the repository.

But no one has responded yet. Now I want to update my homebrew installation. Which fails of course, since I have local changes that have not yet been committed. So I followed the instructions on [the homebrew wiki](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Formula-Cookbook), which tells me to do all sorts of funny things with git. Now git, I have no experience with.

I guess it all went rather fine until it says I should `push`.

```
git push git@github.com:myname/homebrew.git
```

Obviously, I substituted my Github name for `myname`, but it would still fail saying

> Permission denied (publickey)
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

This is rather sad. I would have liked to contribute my little fix. Funny enough, after doing all this, `brew update` would work again.

Anyway, why is `git push` not working for me? How can I contribute my fix to the awesome homebrew project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you hit the `fork` button like the instructions said?  If you didn't do that the operation would fail in this manner because you don't have a repository to push to.

If you did do that, you might want to take a look at [GitHub's SSH troubleshooting page](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/) to figure out what might be going wrong and how to fix it.

Alternatively, you can sidestep those issues by pushing over HTTP instead.  To do so, use this command:

```
git push https://yourname@github.com/yourname/homebrew.git
```

Comment: yeah, well, RTFM was the answer…